# Add Export Button and Function to Custom Post Type in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to build a custom plugin that allows users to edit templates and export as HTML.

I need help with the following:

1. a button that initiates an export function
2. a listener that waits for the button to be pressed
3. a dummy export function that does something simple (e.g. downloads a blank text file)

I've setup the templates as a custom post type and added meta boxes using the Metabox plugin.

I've tried adding an additional meta box which acts as a button, but instead of directing the user to the &submit=true, it updates the post.

Here is the code:

```
function add_export_meta_box(){

add_meta_box('peg-export', 'Export', 'export_meta_box', 'email-template', 'side', 'low');}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_export_meta_box'); 

function export_meta_box()
{?>
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="?page=<?php echo $_GET['page']?>&export=true">
    <input type="hidden" name="export" value="1">
    <input type="submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Export Template" id="export-template"/>

</form>
<?php }
```

Once the button is successfully working, I'm unsure how to get the page to download the template inside the browser.

I'm a little out of my depth here, so I'd appreciate any help.

Muchos gracias, 
:)

Comment: what url does this code `action="?page=<?php echo $_GET['page']?>&export=true"` generate?

Comment: You'd need to create a separate file with `header("Content-type: application/force-download");` and additional header that describes what are you downloading, and with functionality you need (say echoing out the created `HTML` template) inside. Then you'd need to put that file in your button (anchor) and with js prevent the default action, and just force download (because you don't want to reload a page or go to that file). All in all, if you are not skilled, better pay someone who is...

Comment: That line generates a save post response at present.